# Password Protect Pages Reverting To Homepage With Include

Tags: php

I'm trying to put together a Members Only Section on our choir's website (just a low level security using a simple static Username/Password, that all the choir will know).  So far, the file itself is working fine.  If I pull it up directly by entering the directory name it will come up & if the correct details entered will move on as it's meant to, also working giving an Incorrect Password & a Logout option, so no problems there (by the look of it).
However, I want all this to be Included from the index.php in the root folder.  As it is, the login page opens as it should, with the little box there, but as soon as the details are entered it moves back to the home page.

The script on the login page is as follows:

```
    <?php

session_start(); // start session cookies
require("/home/users/web/b282/ipg.newmusicmakerscom/members/Login.class.php"); // pull in file
$login = new Login; // create object login

$login->authorize(); // make user login

?>
```

Which "Should" move on to open the "You have logged in successfully - Click here to continue" part of the page, which it only does if accessed directly, although it just reverts to the initial index.php?page=phppages/home.php wotsit whether or not the correct details were entered.

As you can see, I'm already using an absolute pathway to the Login.class.php file (and that's being accessed fine).  The relevant (or not) script linking to the login page from the index menu is as follows:

```
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
  <li class="topfirst"><a href="#" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;"><span>Home</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=phppages/home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=/home/users/web/b282/ipg.newmusicmakerscom/members/index.php">Members Only</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us Login.class.php ?

Comment: If the user's login credentials are not stored in a session/cookie or otherwise sent by the client to the server, then any page which is restricted will redirect back to the index.  I know you are probably enjoying writing this, but you could set up a free wordpress site and that will allow you to restrict content to certain users...

Comment: You should **never** allow to include any file added by a parameter. You open the server up to attacks that way.